# Screen Tap -> Go forward with code; Java, Android

Tags: android, onclick, touch, screen

Guys I have been self learning for barely few days and I really searched forums for the answer. 
I can't get through in java/android with second tap needed, after pressing button.
The first, correct one, would make button change colour to green(if correct) and add to the score, second should move to next question. Your help much appreciated.

```
    mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mButtonChoice1.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                mScore = mScore + 1;
                mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF00);
                updateScore(mScore);
```

//Here I need your help - I need an action 'update question' to perform after another screen tap (on the screen not the button only)

```
                updateQuestion();

            } else {
                updateQuestion();
```

Regards'
PapaT

Comment: Do you mean the second tap should create another question?

Comment: Should proceed to next question.
As for now, just after the first tap (answer basically), the question changes. I want it to remain until second tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this, it will alternate if the click updates the score and sets the color or if it moves to the next question.

```
mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    boolean fistClick = true;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (firstClick) {
            if (mButtonChoice1.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                mScore++;
                mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF00);
                updateScore(mScore);
            }
            firstClick = false;
        } else {
            updateQuestion();
            firstClick = true;
        }
    }
});
```